# Finding the expiry date of membership to an Azure AD Role using Powershell Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

New to this, but been a viewer for some time! Thank you for taking a look.

I am looking to try and find the expiry date of membership to the various roles in Azure AD/Entra ID. In my environment, I have several users that are members of the Global Admin role. I can see that one user has the End Date property set for their access to this group. I have used the Graph modules for Powershell to identify the users that are members of this (And other) roles, presenting the ID number to an array so that I can get user details to present in another format. What I am interested in getting is the property for End Date. My aim ultimately is to highlight the accounts that do not have this property set, leaving purely the break glass accounts in place.

The code as it stands:

```
$AllRoles = Get-MgDirectoryRole #Get a list of all roles in Azure
$RoleUsers = @()
foreach ($CurrentRole in $AllRoles) {
    $CurrentRole.DisplayName
    $CurrentRole.Id
    $CurrentRole | FL
    $AllRoleUsers = Get-MgDirectoryRoleMemberAsUser -DirectoryRoleId $CurrentRole.Id #Get all user objects
    $AllRoleGroups = Get-MgDirectoryRoleMemberAsGroup -DirectoryRoleId $CurrentRole.Id #Get all group objects
    foreach ($ThisRoleUser in $AllRoleUsers) {
        #Does the account have a date set?
        $RoleUsers += $ThisRoleUser.Id #Add all users to the array
    }
    foreach ($ThisRoleGroup in $AllRoleGroups) {
        $AllRoleGroupMembers = Get-MgGroupMemberAsUser -GroupId $ThisRoleGroup.Id #Get all users in a group
        foreach ($ThisRoleGroupMembers in $AllRoleGroupMembers) {
            #Does the account have a date set?
            $RoleUsers += $ThisRoleGroupMembers.Id #Add to array
        }
    }
    $RoleUsers.Count
}
```

I would like to put the test in the foreach loops, so that I can test for the existence of the value, and add to an array if, or if not, existing. I can view the value here under the assigned roles for user as seen in the screenshot.[View of user assigned roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLWbY.png) I have attempted to use the Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment cmdlet to gain this, but I cannot find the piece I need! The help page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.governance/get-mgrolemanagementdirectoryroleassignment?view=graph-powershell-1.0) does appear to indicate at the bottom that there is a field that can be used in a hash table called EndDateTime, which does sound perfect, but I cannot find how to get this information out. I dont know if I am looking at the correct cmdlet even, I just dont know where to try and find this snippet of information. I am figuring that its not in the role definition, its not in the mguser cmdlet, as its not a user setting. Hence looking at the assignment cmdlet. Anyway, all help and thoughts gratefully received. I may be doing this in a silly way, so if there is a better way then all thoughts are welcomed.
I am staying clear of the other cmdlets, and trying to stick with the Microsoft Graph ones at this time.

I have attempted to use a number of cmdlets within the Microsoft Graph offering. The latest is the Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment. This one does appear to hint at a property called EndDateTime, but I cannot find how to get this showing.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried finding the expiry date of membership to an Azure AD Role using Powershell Microsoft Graph and able to figureout the issues facing here.

It seems that youre right with the `Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment` cmdlet. The `EndDateTime` property is indeed what you need to look for to determine the expiry date of a role assignment in Azure AD.

The key steps to follow to include the logic for checking the `EndDateTime`

- Use `Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment` to get role
  assignments along with their `EndDateTime`.
- Based on the `EndDateTime`, determine if the role is permanent or temporary.

**Updated script:**

```
$AllRoles = Get-MgDirectoryRole # Get a list of all roles in Azure
$RoleUsers = @()
$RoleUsersWithEndDate = @()
$RoleUsersWithoutEndDate = @()

foreach ($CurrentRole in $AllRoles) {
    $CurrentRole.DisplayName
    $CurrentRole.Id
    $CurrentRole | FL
    $AllRoleAssignments = Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -Filter "roleDefinitionId eq '$($CurrentRole.Id)'"

    foreach ($Assignment in $AllRoleAssignments) {
        $UserId = $Assignment.PrincipalId
        $User = Get-MgUser -UserId $UserId

        if ($Assignment.EndDateTime -ne $null) {
            # Role has an EndDateTime set
            $RoleUsersWithEndDate += $User
        } else {
            # Role does not have an EndDateTime set
            $RoleUsersWithoutEndDate += $User
        }

        $RoleUsers += $User
    }
}

# Display counts
"Total users with roles: $($RoleUsers.Count)"
"Users with EndDateTime set: $($RoleUsersWithEndDate.Count)"
"Users without EndDateTime set: $($RoleUsersWithoutEndDate.Count)"
```

You can then further analyze or export these arrays as needed. This should help you identify accounts that do not have the `EndDateTime` property set.

ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadusermembership?view=azureadps-2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-powershell

[List unifiedRoleAssignments - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell)

[List roleEligibilityScheduleRequests - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roleeligibilityschedulerequests?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)